# nginx proxy_cache_key with a single $scheme

Tags: linux, nginx, web

I have tested proxy_cache_key with a single $scheme

```
 proxy_cache_key $scheme;
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
```

Then I request one to cache.

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/a.html
```

Then I requested again to confirm the cache

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/a.html
```

No problem

Then I request other url

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/b.html
```

And hope that it hits cache because the key is $scheme

but it gave me the content of b.html

Why      `proxy_cache_key $scheme;` does not work?

Answer (score 1):

The headers from the proxied server response can change the "final" cache key.

From https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ignore_headers :

> If not disabled, processing of these header fields has the following effect:
>
> - “X-Accel-Expires”, “Expires”, “Cache-Control”, “Set-Cookie”, and “Vary” set the parameters of response caching;

You can check if those headers are included in the response and/or try ignoring them.

Comment: I was messing with cookies, and I had a hard time understanding why nginx was still taking into account request "Cookie" (even after ''proxy_set_header Cookie "''). "proxy_ignore_headers Vary" fixed it!